# Publishing a local asp.net core web app to an azure app service

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a local asp.net core 3.1 MVC app that queries a local SQL Server database.  This is my Development environment.  My Production environment is an Azure app service and Azure SQL Server database.  I am using Visual Studio 2019 to deploy my app.  The deployment process works, but I can't figure out how to tell the app to use the Azure SQL Server connection string once my app is deployed.

I've done the following:

- Created an appsettings.json and an appsettings.Development.json file with the same connection string name in both
- Added a connection string to my app service
- Changed my ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT value to Production

I still get this message after I deploy:
[image]

I've seen tutorials on how to deploy static web sites to Azure, but I didn't see any that address my scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the tutorial you need: [Build an ASP.NET Core and Azure SQL Database app in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-dotnetcore-sqldb-app?pivots=platform-windows)

You might forget to configure the server firewall rule:
[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Please let me know if this help you or not. @user1647160